# SPE remoting throws error 'You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.' on calling Invoke-RemoteScript

Tags: powershell-extensions

I installed Sitecore Powershell extension 5.1 on my sitecore 9.0.2 which is in azure PaaS. The imported SPE remoting module 5.1 to my windows powershell(5.1) on my local machine. 
I enabled remoting in config and allow the role sitecore\IsAdministrator.
Now I run the following script from my windows powershell ISE

```
$session = New-ScriptSession -Username admin -Password b -ConnectionUri https://********-cm.azurewebsites.net

Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Write-Host "Hi" }

Stop-ScriptSession -Session $session
```

I get the following error

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\kchithiraisenan\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SPE\Invoke-RemoteScript.ps1:344 char:21
+                     $taskResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try without having the `Write-Host`. You may try `-ScriptBlock { "Hi" }` or `-ScriptBlock { Get-Item "master:\sitecore\content\Home" -Language "en" }` and see if you have the same error

Comment: That did not work. But I found the issue. New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet did not create an object and was throwing error internally that the 'Underlying connection was closed unexpectedly' Then i added ```[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12``` before the callinf New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet and now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet did not create an object and was throwing error internally that the 'Underlying connection was closed unexpectedly' Then adding the follwing line
`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` 
before the calling New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet fixed it.

New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet is used in Invoke-RemoteScript.ps1 file

Comment: Thanks to this page - https://community.meraki.com/t5/Developers-APIs/Invoke-WebRequest-The-underlying-connection-was-closed-An/td-p/22975